# Remove blackhole from Exim4 user

Tags: exim, exim4, blackhole

I am waiting for a very important mail. I have noticed in the logs it is not arriving because of something called blackhole in Exim4.

He you can see the log:

```
exim[22056]: 2017-06-01 11:42:35 1dGMch-0005jk-KY <= no_reply_support@trust-provider.com H=mail1.comodogroup.com (mcmail2.mcr.colo.comodo.net) [91.199.212.133] P=esmtps X=TLS1.2:ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:256 S=7762 id=AdQcsERfObOWslyWQUivgQ@mcmail2.mcr.colo.comodo.net T="ORDER #73033027 - Domain Control Validation for mail.mailserver.hu" from <no_reply_support@trust-provider.com> for postmaster[at]mailserver.hu
exim[22266]: 2017-06-01 11:42:35 1dGMch-0005jk-KY => :blackhole: <postmaster[at]mailserver.hu> R=blackhole_localparts
```

Here is the /etc/aliases file content:

```
# /etc/aliases
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
root: :blackhole:
clamav: root
monit: root
```

Can You advice where can I remove this blackhole? The MTA is Exim version 4.84_2 #1 built 02-Jan-2017 18:43:30

In the Exim4.conf the is a part, maybe this is the responsible for it?

```
blackhole_localparts:
        driver = redirect
        local_parts = devnull : postmaster
        data = :blackhole:
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Exim4.conf I had to remove the blackhole_localparts section and then it arrived.